# Como realizar un CASE en una consulta en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

[image]

Buen dia amigos,espero puedan ayudarme con la siguiente consulta, estoy usando la base de datos de NorthWind.

```
Select OrderID,   
CASE
    WHEN Subtotal>1000 THEN 'SI'
    WHEN Subtotal>1000 THEN 'NO'

END AS BonoAlEmpleado   
from [Order Subtotals]
```

[image]

Comment: Has probado algo? Añade las pruebas que hayas hecho y entonces podremos ayudarte, de no ser así, lo mas seguro es que tu pregunta acabe cerrada por falta de información. Revisate [ask] para saber como realizar una buena pregunta.

Comment: En un momento subo una captura de lo que he echo

Comment: Deberias subir el código sin captura, para que podamos copiarlo para poder probar lo que has hecho y modificarlo respecto a lo que tienes hecho (ahorras tiempo a la gente que quiere ayudarte).

Comment: Tomare en cuenta tus comentarios amigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis en tu consulta SQL.

Primero, tienes la misma comprobación en los 2 casos (`Subtotal>1000`), de esta manera nunca te va a devolver un **NO**, y los casos que no cumplan esto te aparecerán como `NULL`, como muestras en tus pruebas.

Si te fijas en la documentación del [CASE de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), indica que usas el `CASE WHEN` para el `IF`, y entonces el `ELSE`. Siguiendo esta lógica tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Select OrderID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Subtotal > 1000 THEN 'SI' 
        ELSE 'NO' 
    END AS BonoAlEmpleado 
FROM [Order Subtotals]
```

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, no me había dado cuenta de ese error

Comment: Si no me equivoco, al tener un espacio en el nombre de tabla tienes que mantener los corchetes [], no he podido editarlo porque son solo 2 caracteres.

Comment: @Marc Cierto, se me ha escapado ponerlos, gracias